# Identification of rare (?) pieces

Tags: part-identification

Recently, I bought a large LEGO collection in which, during the sorting, I found some pieces I'm completely unable to identify. Moreover, seeing some of them I doubt if they are LEGO at all (could be parts of an assembly though).

Here is a photo of the unidentified pieces:

[image]

I hope you can recognize them, please let me know if more photos would be necessary.

Higher resolution photos of #2 with the cup for scale (I really doubt it is a LEGO item but it might be a part of a motor or something):

[image]

Comment: Can we use a 1x1 brick for comparison?  I have no cups in my collection.

Comment: 11 is a plastic ring with a single threaded hole on one side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 is a pin used to hold train track pieces together during shipping. It can be discarded but some people find uses for it since it fits in a. minifig's hands.

Many of the others are official Lego as can be seen by the brand name printed on them. On the large pieces you should be able to see an ID number printed underneath which will help you out. I'll work through identifying some of the others.

3: [Bionicle Gear 8 Tooth with Rhotuka Spinner Rod 2.5L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1307)

4: [Appendage Spiky / Bionicle Spine / Seaweed / Plant Vine](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55236)

5: [Modified 2x2 Racing Driver, no head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x351)

6: [Bar 1L with Top Stud and 2 Side Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92690) (credit to [Victorious Victini](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10333/56))

7: [Train Coupling New](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2920)

8: [Bionicle 2x3 Axle Connector with Tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42074)

9: [Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Locking with 1 Finger Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=989)

12: [Leg Skeleton with Black Square Foot](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93062c01#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

13: [Bar 1 x 8 with Brick 1 x 2 Curved Top End](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30359b) (most likely this newer version, but there are some older ones as well) (credit to [Victorious Victini](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10333/56))

14: [Fairing, 1x2 Stepped with Two Pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47501)

15: [Batwing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0203#T=C)

16: [Modified 1x4 with Angled Tubes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61072)

17: Not Lego

18: [Fire hose nozzle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60849#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

19: [Bionicle Weapon Cordak Ammo](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=78202)

20: [Road Sign Clip-on 2 x 2 Square with Curved Blue Lines and Small Black Squares Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30258pb018)

21: [Bat-a-rang](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98721&idColor=11)

22: [LEGO Minifig, Weapon Bladed Claw](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88811) (mostly from Wolverine)

23: [Horn Large](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87747#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

24: [Minifig, Utensil Space Scanner Tool.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=277) (credit to [Rin Rio-Oki](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10334/))

Comment: #17 which is listed as "Not Lego" looks awfully close to the color scheme used for several [flame](https://brickset.com/parts?query=flame) parts, though I can't find any shape matches and they're generally red on the bottom. Is it known to be a specific kind of non-LEGO piece?

Comment: I am pretty sure I threw out a few of those from my last bulk purchase because they had space for a Lego logo but did not have one, so I assumed they were off brand.

Comment: I'm fairly sure #17 is from Mega Bloks, in at the very least the Dragons sets. There is a smallish one shown (not the big ones at the top, closer to the middle) in <https://dragonsuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Yulmar?file=Yul_b4.JPG>.

Answer (score 7):

I found a few more:

6: [Ø3.2 Shaft With Cored Knob](https://brickset.com/parts/4640844)

13: [Brick With Shaft 1X8X1](https://brickset.com/parts/4124064)

Comment: Thanks for adding those, I've added them into [Craig's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10332) so that we can have a single definitive accepted answer :)

Answer (score 7):

A Few More:

02:  [<s>LegoTechnic Driving Ring Extension.</s>](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32187&name=Technic%20Driving%20Ring%20Extension&category=%5BTechnic%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

24: [Minifig, Utensil Space Scanner Tool.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=277#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: The 24th is a match, but the second one's not. I'll upload a closer photo soon.

Comment: Agreed:  Mine looks too big.  Could the OP post more pics with the pieces pushed over, so we can get a sense of depth?

Comment: Thanks for finding that Rin Rio-Oki, I've added 24 to Craig's answer to help towards a single definitive answer :)